# Delta Live CDC for Aggregate State Tables

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake, aws-databricks, delta-live-tables

As far as I can tell from the documentation, I can not accomplish a specific migration from Delta to Delta Live that I would love to do... but I want to see if I might be missing a solution.

Currently, i have a number of aggregate batch Delta tables that upsert new records on a daily basis, keeping only a very basic set of information.
`key, first_seen, last_seen`

with normal Delta upserts, I do this by grabbing the new data, creating a data frame with the last seen information and conditionally updating the `last_seen` value or inserting all. so it is like

```
existing.alias(‘existing’).merge(
summary.alias('updates'), "existing.key = updates.key")\
.whenMatchedUpdate(condition="updates.last_seen > existing.last_seen", 
  set = { "last_seen": "updates.last_seen"})\
.whenNotMatchedInsertAll()\
.execute()
```

I really would like to bring this into Delta Live pipelines and change it to an incremental update. Life would be so great. I only want to keep current information so this should match SCD Type 1.

From the Databricks documentation on CDC, I can not see how to do an upsert on a subset of columns which also performs an `whenNotMatchedInsertAll()`.

Any thoughts?